# Every request hits server twice in Appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have small app in appengine. Every request hits the server twice in my local dev server.
In debug mode i can see that the **get** method called twice.
Its happening in both chrome and firefox browsers.
here is the log from my localserver..

```
INFO     2011-03-12 00:44:31,076 dev_appserver.py:3317] "GET /movie/tanu_weds_manu/rating-review-video HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2011-03-12 00:44:32,345 dev_appserver.py:3317] "GET /css/fb.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2011-03-12 00:44:32,588 dev_appserver.py:3317] "GET /css/wianga-movie.0.1.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2011-03-12 00:45:46,648 dev_appserver.py:3317] "GET /movie/tanu_weds_manu/rating-review-video HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2011-03-12 00:45:46,911 dev_appserver.py:3317] "GET /img/wianga-fb-50.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2011-03-12 00:45:47,177 dev_appserver.py:3317] "GET /img/arrow_green.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2011-03-12 00:45:47,470 dev_appserver.py:3317] "GET /image/movie/tanu_weds_manu HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2011-03-12 00:45:47,717 dev_appserver.py:3317] "GET /js/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2011-03-12 00:45:47,970 dev_appserver.py:3317] "GET /js/wianga.0.1.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2011-03-12 00:46:37,473 dev_appserver.py:3317] "GET /movie/tanu_weds_manu/rating-review-video HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

**Updated**: Its getting worse,i cheked the logs in app console.There it hits more than 3 times for a request.

```
handlers:
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/img/favicon.ico
  upload: static/img/favicon.ico
- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: static/robots.txt
  upload: static/robots.txt
- url: /img
  static_dir: static/img
- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images
- url: /css
  static_dir: static/css
- url: /js
  static_dir: static/js
- url: /image/.*
  script: /wianga/pages/common/ImageController.py
- url: /task/.*
  script: /wianga/pages/task/TaskController.py
- url: /browse/.*
  script: /wianga/site/Browse.py
- url: /movie/(.*)/rating-review-video/
  script: /wianga/site/MoviePage.py
- url: /movie/(.*)/rating-review-video
  script: /wianga/site/MoviePage.py
- url: /404
  script: /wianga/404/404.py
- url: /api/.*
  script: /wianga/api/ApiController.py
- url: /.*
  script: /wianga/site/Home.py
```

Am getting same behavior in hellowrld application from appengine turorial...
**App.yaml**

```
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.py
```

**Log for hello world example for single request...**

```
INFO     2011-03-12 06:08:06,299 dev_appserver_main.py:507] Running application wianga-movie on port 8080: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2011-03-12 06:08:12,506 dev_appserver.py:3317] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2011-03-12 06:08:13,721 dev_appserver.py:3317] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2011-03-12 06:08:13,838 dev_appserver.py:3317] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2011-03-12 06:08:13,953 dev_appserver.py:3317] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if this pattern repeats for pages coming from something besides the AppEngine server? I have a hard time believing that there is something about the AppEngine dev server that is causing this problem.

Comment: @Adam Crossland In chrome and firefox(using firebug ),the request went only once.But server triggers "def get(self):" method twice.if u want my code and app.yaml ..i will post it here.

Comment: Those GETS in the log seem to indicate that something is making an http request to that URL.  Is it possible that a cron job or taskqueue task is using that URL?  That could happen if your wildcard handler is above your taskqueue handler in your app.yaml.  Also, are you doing anything in jquery, or a div/iframe that might be requesting that URL again?

Comment: @calvin i dont have any cron/task for this url.But i have task for other urls.i updated my question with app.yaml .Is there any link explains best practice for app.yaml structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I set up my app.yaml I just poured through this page: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html
You have to think like a regular expression parser.  Anything that fails to match the preceding expressions will fall through to your wildcard handler and cause weirdness.

One thing I notice is that you should add `login: admin` to your task queue handler. This will prevent external requests from hitting that URL accidentally.

Also, when you are submitting tasks to your handler, if you don't include the trailing slash (`/task?blah=something` instead of `/task/?blah=something`) the request would fall through to your wildcard handler and get sent to Home.py.  That could also happen for `/image/`, `/browse/` and `/api/`.  You should put logging calls into those handlers to make sure they are getting called when expected.

Nothing jumps out at me as obviously wrong in your app.yaml though.  But since there are GETs showing up in your log, that indicates that something is requesting that URL, and it's not just the `get` method getting called twice internally.

Edit:

Hold on a sec, just noticed that you have this in your app.yaml twice. You shouldn't need to do that.

```
- url: /movie/(.*)/rating-review-video/ 
  script: /wianga/site/MoviePage.py 
- url: /movie/(.*)/rating-review-video 
  script: /wianga/site/MoviePage.py`
```

Try replacing with:

```
- url: /movie/(.*)/rating-review-video.*
  script: /wianga/site/MoviePage.py`
```

Edit2:

Try adding this to the top of your `get` method:

```
 logging.info('environ: ' + str(self.request._environ))
```

Pop the output into a beautifier ( http://jsbeautifier.org/ ) to make it more readable, and take a look at the REQUEST_METHOD, QUERY_STRING, HTTP_USER_AGENT, HTTP_COOKIE, PATH_INFO, and HTTP_REFERER params to see where the requests are actually coming from.  If they are all coming from your browser then there is something weird in your html, like hidden iframes (are you using Channel API?).

Also, try going to http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/queues and making sure there aren't any old tasks hanging around.

Comment: thanks for the reply.i tried to run helloworld example given in app engine tutorial..In that also am getting the same behavior.I upgraded my appengine to 1.4.2 yesterday..will this is causing this problem..I updated my question with helloword app config and its log.

Comment: I'm running 1.4.2 as well, and it's not exhibiting this behavior.

Comment: request from firefox gives two entry in log.From chrome four entries in the log.i will reinstall the 1.4.2 and try once again...

Comment: i inspected the environ data ,from firefox 3.6,4,IE8,opera11,safari5 sends one request.But chrome 10 sends 3 request.I tried this for hello world app.For time being am not going to dig into chrome issues.thanks a lot calvin.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me a hint about the environment variables and in my case, after every request the browser (Google Chrome) also requested the favicon.ico, but I didn't have one set in the .yaml file so the request moved to the .* script.
After setting the favicon.ico file, everything works just fine.